# I need to execute some code beyond any event handler. Is it posssible in C# Windows Forms to do that?

Tags: c#, events, handler

I just need to execute some code. But I don't need to put it in any event handler.
Is there any posibility to do that in C# language? In particular, in Windows Form. 
In other words how to execute a code beyond any event handlers like "button click", "mouse click", "timer tick" and so forth.

```
 if (!boolA)
    {
       //do here something

    }
 else return;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't want the code to be in any event handler but then you want code to be executed in response to some click event

Comment: I need somehow to work with operator "if" and variable "booA" beyond any event handlers. Is it possible? For example, to get it working I must put  this code at least into Button_Click. Don't it?\

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the constructor of the form or double click your form and put the code in the `Load` handler (although this is an event handler but it is very customary to put code here that needs to be executed before the form is shown). You can also put the code in the class named `Program.cs` and that code will be executed when the application starts-just put the code before you show the entry form.

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but this is not the way. The code will be executed  one time while Form initialization. I need it to be executed constantly.

Comment: @Msorich Please explain why it is not the way? You said you do not know where to put code aside from handlers, where else would you put it aside from what I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I need it to be executed constantly. Not only while Form initializing. There should be proper way to do that in C# language.

Comment: @Msorich Why you do not want to use a time? You can also use another thread and put it in an endless loop?